# In Ubuntu 19.04, "Indicator Stickynotes" stopped working. Doesn't open. Doesn't show in taskbar

Tags: gnome, indicator, 19.04

```
pranav@inspiron-5548:~$indicator-stickynotes
Indicator stickynotes already running.
```

That's the terminal approach. And below given gif is GUI approach of opening this app:

[image: act of trying to use sticky notes]

As u can see in gif above, the app is not responding at all.

What should I do? I really need this a lot. It's nice and simple. Alash...
                          [image: App image]

*Don't mention other "Sticky notes" unless u have no opinion to give.*

Comment: How did you installed it? What is the output of `apt-cache policy indicator-stickynotes`? Why are you trying to run it as root? What is your desktop environment?

Comment: @N0rbert i used "sudo apt install indicator-stickynotes" after adding PPA. As u can see "-H" is given, so it doesn't give the app actual root, I heard somewhere its safe. (newbie)

Comment: On my clean 19.04 VM with GNOME Shell it works out the box (used `ppa:umang/indicator-stickynotes` PPA). Do you have installed any GNOME Shell extensions for tray / indicator management?

Comment: no, do i have to?! "tray / indicator management" @N0rbert

Comment: it was working without the extension u said. But from last 8 hours, I can't make it work. @N0rbert But in case this is the list of all extension I have installed: https://imgur.com/dYAYuTL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reinstall *AppIndicator/KStatusNotifierItem support for GNOME Shell* with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
```

---

The `indicator-stickynotes` will not work without it and will show the message from your question:

> ```
> $ indicator-stickynotes 
> Indicator stickynotes already running.
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot @N0rbert . That really solved the thing. 1  billion thanks.

Comment: This doesnt work for ubuntu 16.04